# CKEditor Crashes Edge Browser when you click on SOURCE

Tags: windows, ckeditor, microsoft-edge

Just upgraded to Windows 10. Switching to SOURCE mode in CKEditor crashes the entire browser and cases to refresh. No way to access source.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Whenever you see a browser crash, you should report that problem to the company that develops that browser as they are the only ones that can really fix those kind of problems.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a bug tracker. The issue has been reported to [CKEditor](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13525) and [Edge](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1577449/edge-browser-crashes-when-using-ckeditor-toggling-from-wysiwyg-to-source-mode) bug trackers. Please follow the issues for the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge is a new product, and so far, it has quite a few issues that need ironing out.

CKEditor introduced initial Edge support in version 4.5, but there are quite a few bugs that were reported by us to Microsoft and that need to be fixed on their side.

The issue that you describe was actually reported by us, too, you can find it here: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1577449/edge-browser-crashes-when-using-ckeditor-toggling-from-wysiwyg-to-source-mode

Anyone interested in having this fixed is probably most welcome to comment the bug report to highlight it's a show-stopper for many users. Sorry about any inconvenience caused.

Comment: CKEditor is not alone, there is also SCEditor running into problems with this "new" browser resp. with EdgeHTML: https://github.com/samclarke/SCEditor/issues/501

Answer (score 0):

As MicroSoft says this problem has been solved after update 1511.

Check this link: [Browser crashes when using CKEditor (toggling from WYSIWYG to source mode)](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1577449/edge-browser-crashes-when-using-ckeditor-toggling-from-wysiwyg-to-source-mode)